# How should I design my thread so that I don't need to instantiate a generic?

Tags: java, multithreading, generics

I've got several thread classes that use different comparison methods. I've implemented them as extending an abstract class. For example,

```
public abstract class MatcherThread implements Runnable{
    List<String> clusters;
    int output;

    public MatcherThread(List<String> clusters){
        this.clusters = clusters;
    }

    public void run()
    {
        for(List<String> c: clusters) {
            compare(c);
        }
    }

    public int getOutput(){
       return output;
    }

    protected abstract void compare(String c);
}

public class MaxLength extends MatcherThread{
    public MaxLength(List<String> clusters){
      super(clusters);
      this.output = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    }

    protected void compare(String c){
      if(c.length() > output) output = c.length();
    }
}

public class MinLength extends MatcherThread{
    public MinLength(List<String> clusters){
      super(clusters);
      this.output = 0;
    }

    protected void compare(String c){
      if(c.length() < output) output = c.length();
    }
}
```

Now, I want to have a class which can run either thread. My first thought was to make this class generic, but distributing work to the threads requires instantiating them.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class Matcher<T extends MatcherThread>{

     protected List<Integer> runAll(List<String> clusters, int nthreads) {
        int n = clusters.size();
        int poolSize = nthreads;
        int step = n/poolSize;
        ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(poolSize);
        List<T> tasks = new ArrayList<T>();
        for (int i = 0; i < poolSize; i++) {
            int start = i*step;
            int end = i == poolSize -1 ? n: (i+1)*step;

            List<List<String>> subcluster = new ArrayList<List<String>>(){{
                for (int ind=start; ind < end; ind++) add(clusters(ind));
            }};

            T task = new T(subcluster); //This is not allowed.
            tasks.add(task);
        }
        CompletableFuture<?>[] futures = tasks.stream().map(task -> CompletableFuture.runAsync(task, es)).toArray(CompletableFuture[]::new);
        CompletableFuture.allOf(futures).join();
        es.shutdown();

        List<Integer> output = new List<Integer>();
        for(T t : tasks) {
            output.add(t.getOutput());
        }
        return output;
    }
}
```

How can I redesign my classes, so that instantiating a generic type is not necessary, but I can still switch easily between comparison functions?

Comment: Not related to your question, but you can have your subcluster generation be done by libraries if you want to drop some "not that fun" code from your sample. E.g. [guava's partition](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html#partition-java.util.List-int-) or from [Apache Collections](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/ListUtils.html#partition-java.util.List-int-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In that case, you typically supply some kind of factory to your Matcher which takes care of creating the appropriate thread. In Java 8 you can e.g. use the [`Supplier`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Supplier.html) interface:

```
public class Matcher {

    private final Supplier<? extends MatcherThread> threadSupplier;

    public Matcher(Supplier<? extends MatcherThread> threadSupplier) {
        this.threadSupplier = threadSupplier;
    }

     protected List<Integer> runAll(List<String> clusters, int nthreads) {

        // …
        MatcherThread task = threadSupplier.get();
        task.setSubcluster(subcluster); // refactor to allow setter injection
        tasks.add(task);
        // …

    }

}
```

Then, instantiate the matcher as follows:

```
Matcher matcher = new Matcher(() -> new MaxLength());
```

This assumes that you add a `setSubcluster` method, instead of the constructor injection. Alternatively, you could also use a [`Function`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html), or implement your own factory interface to stick to the constructor injection.